# web deploy azure slow to publish and fail

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-cloud-services

I have trying to publish 5 projects, in two different accounts (3 web app and 2 Cloud Service - classic), I am having problems to publish the projects on the last week, my internet connection is ok.

Important to mention that before use to take 20 minutes to publish a cloud service. Sometimes the publication works, but after some attempts and now the VS Studio use to freeze when start to publish.

Right now I am trying to publish a Cloud Service, took more than 1 hour to show the first log and then fail.

12:37:42 AM - Applying Diagnostics extension.

12:38:01 AM - Preparing deployment for xxxxxxx - 7/19/2016 11:33:33 PM with Subscription ID 'xxxxxxxx' using Service Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...

12:38:01 AM - Connecting...

12:38:01 AM - Verifying storage account 'xxxstorage'...

12:38:02 AM - Uploading Package...

12:41:35 AM - Stopping xxxx

12:41:36 AM - A security token validation error occured for the received JWT token.

Comment: What's the status of instances in your Cloud Service ? Meanwhile, from your error message, I recommend you can try to sign out and sign in your Azure Account in VS again. Any information, please let me know.

Comment: The instance is running. Still not working even after the sign out and sign in. Can be any VS update?

Comment: Even trying to publish the webdeploy local is taking a long time.

Comment: The problem was some update, even reinstalling the VS works, I needed to reset the windows.

Comment: Nice. It appeared that some VS components changed.